# How to speed up app opening times

Tags: android

I've pretty much completed my Android app but I'm having a problem with the time it takes for the app to open. It takes roughly 10 seconds from the app icon pressed to the app actually opening to a loading screen (uses async to get some data when it opens).

This is not on the emulator but on a physical device, it's not the quickest of phones but Google maps for example takes around 2 seconds to open so the device isn't the primary cause.

What can I look at to figure out why this takes so long?

Comment: Please provide the source code, what exactly do you perform on the app start

Comment: Are you wanting like the on create for the main activity? Not super confident with Android development.

Comment: You can track method execution times (for example, with Log.d calls). Provide the code that executes for a long time.

Comment: Use Traceview and `StrictMode` to determine where your time is being spent.